# Task.wait vs async await

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have been looking into upgrading the way that we do async tasks in our software. For years the software has been running in .net 2.5 and the team previous, decided to implement their own async task architecture which for the most part is OK but difficult to use for more complicated things.

I was watching a tutorial which explained tasks in C# really well but then started looking at async methods and the await keyword to keep the software up to date. My question is, why you would want to use async and await over just creating a task and using .wait/.waitAll/.waitAny.

I have read things that say that it isn't creating new threads (which suggests its not as parallel) and that it has a performance overhead.

Can you still apply the wait all one by one methodology? I am guessing since the async returns a task you would just use this to populate your list but that just furthers my argument on why would you bother using it?

Comment: .net 2.5? You mean 2.0 or 3.5?

Comment: You are correct. I didn't upgrade it initially and for some reason 2.5 sounded like the right number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, why you would want to use async and await over just
>   creating a task and using .wait/.waitAll/.waitAny.

A task is merely a promise of your which will complete in the future. **Task != Thread** , and that is an important thing to remember.

> I have read things that say that it isn't creating new threads (which
>   suggests its not as parallel) and that it has a performance overhead.

That depends on how the `Task` is being created.

For example:

```
public async Task<string> GetPageAsync(string url)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

This operations generates no threads, but still returns a `Task<string>`. using `async-await` has *some* overhead because under the covers, the compiler creates a state-machine which manages the execution flow, which has to take care of many things.

While this:

```
return Task.Run(FooOperation);
```

Requests a thread pool thread to run `FooOperation` on.

A task can be generated for doing overlapped IO (like the first example) operations which require no thread at all. When you create a task and use `Wait/WaitAll/WaitAny`, you're **blocking** on the call, and then you end up asking yourself why use that at all and not run it synchronously instead?

For `async-await`, you can use the asynchronous `WhenAny/WhenAll`, which themselfs yield an awaitable which can be asynchronously waited.

Comment: One of the situations we have is that we have to get 3 files and parse them and then once they are all done we merge them all together, so having them run at the same time and waiting for them is better than running synchronously. From what it sounds like you are saying, in that case I would be better using tasks however in something like updating the UI thread use Async?

Comment: How does it achieve the parallelism from the state machine, sorry if that is a dumb question, it's been awhile since I did state machines. Does that mean that it doesn't take advantage of all the cores you have available?

Comment: `async-await` isn't about parallelism, its about concurrency. If you want to do CPU bound work on a list of files, you can use something like `Parallel.ForEach`, which will partition an `IEnumerable` and run each on a separate thread.

Comment: I always thought concurrency and parallelism were interchangeable words, I'll look into the difference more and hopefully that should help me further. I'll mark this as the answer because it has been helpful and you have answered my question. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK, so from a quick google search it all seems to makes sense. The async stuff uses the state machine to flick between the tasks in the list so every task gets a fair bit of usage (I'm guessing that's why people have noticed performance problems). So is task.factory.startnew concurrent as well or does that run on a seperate thread? The tutorial which I was watching showed it working across all 4 cores. Or am I missing something again?

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` offloads work to the threadpool, or spins up on a new thread if you supply it with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I just need to look at our architecture and work out which will be best for what we need. There are a few other task type stuff we need to do as well so I think I will probably have to use a combination of all 3 to get the best out of my software. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: @Keithin8a: If you need to do both parallel and asynchronous code, check out TPL Dataflow.